# Newly setup WSUS all clients stuck at downloading 0%

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update, wsus

Recently I created a newly WSUS setup for the first time and it's all still new to me so be gentle ;-)

I've set up WSUS as described on the internet (pretty basic) and all went well without any problems; I then deployed all new Windows 10 Pro v2004 images via MDT to our office PC's (they were still running Windows 7 Pro):

- During the TaskSequence, I let the Windows machines update via the standard online Windows Updates services, then, as one of the last steps in the TaskSequence, I set the WSUS setting via PowerShell [below] on the clients (since I have to access AD, I cannot set it globally via GPO):

  ```
  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host "============================================================"
  Write-Host "= Setup WSUS...                                            ="
  Write-Host "============================================================"
  Write-Host "Setting WSUS server settings..."
  $RootPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
  if (-Not (Test-Path $RootPath)) { New-Item -Path $RootPath }

  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'TargetGroup' -Value "MyOffice" -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'TargetGroupEnabled' -Value 1 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'UpdateServiceUrlAlternate' -Value 'http://ServerHostname:8530' -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'WUServer' -Value "http://ServerHostname:8530" -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'WUStatsServer' -Value "http://ServerHostname:8530" -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'WUStatusServer' -Value "http://ServerHostname:8530" -Verbose

  Write-Host "Setting Windows Update settings..."
  $RootPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
  if (-Not (Test-Path $RootPath)) { New-Item -Path $RootPath }

  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'AUOptions' -Value 4 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'AutomaticMaintenanceEnabled' -Value 1 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'NoAutoUpdate' -Value 0 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'ScheduledInstallDay' -Value 4 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'ScheduledInstallEveryWeek' -Value 1 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'ScheduledInstallTime' -Value 18 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'UseWUServer' -Value 1 -Verbose
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RootPath -Name 'AllowMUUpdateService' -Value 1 -Verbose
  ```
- On WSUS, I've set the "*Products and Classification*s" to:

  - Products:

    - Microsoft Defender Antivirus
    - Microsoft Edge
    - Microsoft 10, v1903 and later (reminder, the images deployed were v2004)
    - Office 2016
  - Classifications: All
- On WSUS, I set the option: "*Store update files locally on this server*", however this resulted in a "*disk is running out of space*" situation due to the limited space on the server (300GB), so I have set the option: "*Do not store update files locally; computers install from Microsoft Update*" (it's only for 15 computers and we have a fiber uplink, so no problem there). After changing this setting, I've run "*Server Cleanup Wizard*", then called `wsusutil.exe reset`.

The problem is that while all clients see the WSUS server in the network, and all approved updates show up in the clients as "*need to update*", all updates are stuck at "*Downloading 0%*". I googled for several days now and couldn't determine what I'm doing wrong here...

From one, I took the Windows Update log:

```
2020-07-30 08:08:02.9825822 5060  5268  Shared          * START * Service startup
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0243505 5060  5268  Shared          InitializeSus
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0288353 5060  5268  IdleTimer       Non-AoAc machine.  Aoac operations will be ignored.
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0299061 5060  5268  Agent           WU client version 10.0.19041.329
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0311946 5060  5268  Agent           SleepStudyTracker: Machine is non-AOAC. Sleep study tracker disabled.
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0324048 5060  5268  Agent           Base directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution
2020-07-30 08:08:03.0369607 5060  5268  Agent           Datastore directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
2020-07-30 08:08:03.1506026 5060  5268  DataStore       JetEnableMultiInstance succeeded - applicable param count: 5, applied param count: 5
2020-07-30 08:08:04.1723947 5060  5268  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2020-07-30 08:08:04.1737596 5060  5268  Shared          Network state: Disconnected
2020-07-30 08:08:04.2276231 5060  5268  Shared          Power status changed
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430528 5060  5268  Agent           Initializing global settings cache
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430538 5060  5268  Agent           WSUS server: http://ServerHostname:8530
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430544 5060  5268  Agent           WSUS status server: http://ServerHostname:8530
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430573 5060  5268  Agent           Alternate Download Server: http://ServerHostname:8530
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430581 5060  5268  Agent           Fill Empty Content Urls: No
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430586 5060  5268  Agent           Target group: TripleOffice
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430592 5060  5268  Agent           Windows Update access disabled: No
2020-07-30 08:08:05.1430596 5060  5268  Agent           Do not connect to Windows Update Internet locations: No
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0434107 5060  5268  Agent           Initializing Windows Update Agent
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0476802 5060  5268  Agent           Found 1 persisted download calls to restore
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0565487 5060  5268  DownloadManager Subscribing to heartbeat event.
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0590126 5060  5268  Agent           *FAILED* [80070057] Method failed [CClientCallRecorder::LoadPersistedDownloadCalls:5873]
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0604656 5060  5268  DownloadManager Retrieved 1 persisted download jobs
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0619462 5060  5268  Agent           CPersistentTimeoutScheduler | GetTimer, returned hr = 0x00000000
2020-07-30 08:08:07.0619541 5060  5268  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2020-07-30 06:08:09, not idle-only, not network-only
2020-07-30 08:08:10.7272539 5060  5268  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2020-07-30 08:08:10.7273180 5060  5268  IdleTimer       IdleTimer::NetworkStateChanged. Network connected? Yes
2020-07-30 08:08:44.3414919 5060  5268  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7757299 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7758352 5592  1232  ComApi          Byte length of the input buffer for deserialization: 34482
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7783011 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7793505 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserialized installable update Microsoft Edge-Stable Channel Version 84 Update for x64 based Editions (Build 84.0.522.44), UpdateID = {81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7897348 5592  1232  ComApi          Reloading CUpdate 81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200 from datastore...
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7934859 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7935955 5592  1232  ComApi          Byte length of the input buffer for deserialization: 34482
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7945338 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7945650 5592  1232  ComApi          Deserialized installable update Microsoft Edge-Stable Channel Version 84 Update for x64 based Editions (Build 84.0.522.44), UpdateID = {81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
2020-07-30 08:10:08.7945953 5592  1232  ComApi          Reload successful, UpdateID =  81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0, Current deployment action = 1, New deployment action = 1
2020-07-30 08:10:09.7959447 5592  1228  ComApi          * START *   Federated Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = 3gPFupW3bU6J4nJU.1.0)
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8003782 5592  1312  ComApi          Federated Download: Starting download for 1 service(s) (cV = 3gPFupW3bU6J4nJU.1.0)
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8004542 5592  1312  ComApi          * START *   Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator 
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8004552 5592  1312  ComApi          Flags: 0X1100C; Download priority: 2; Network Cost Policy: 0
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8004561 5592  1312  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8004684 5592  1312  ComApi          ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8018595 5060  7600  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8018653 5060  7600  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 11; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8018820 5060  7600  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 11.
2020-07-30 08:10:09.8019029 5592  1312  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975618 5060  7600  DownloadManager * START * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905}]
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975670 5060  7600  DownloadManager Priority = 2, NetworkCostPolicy = 0, Interactive = 1, Download on Battery = 1, Bypass Regulation = 1, Owner is system = 1, Proxy session id = -1, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975677 5060  7600  DownloadManager Updates to download = 1
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975707 5060  7600  Agent             Title = Microsoft Edge-Stable Channel Version 84 Update for x64 based Editions (Build 84.0.522.44)
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975749 5060  7600  Agent             UpdateId = 81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975757 5060  7600  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2975772 5060  7600  Agent                 E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200
2020-07-30 08:10:10.2977472 5060  7600  DownloadManager Regulation: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category High.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.5020846 5060  7600  Reporter        OS Product Type = 0x00000030
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6240260 5060  7600  DownloadManager Queueing update E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200 for download handler request generation.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6250030 5060  7600  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6250064 5060  7600  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 11) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6250086 5060  7600  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905}; ActivationID: 11
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6250296 5060  7600  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 12; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6250324 5060  7600  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 12.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6253086 5060  2472  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with code Call progress and error 0
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6257445 5060  7604  DownloadManager Generating download request for update E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.6269586 5060  7600  DownloadManager * END * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905}] [hr = 0x00000000]
2020-07-30 08:10:10.7357691 5060  7604  Misc            *FAILED* [80070003] Method failed [SusMoveOrCopyDirectoryContentsHelperRecursive:1650]
2020-07-30 08:10:10.7357730 5060  7604  Misc            *FAILED* [80070003] Method failed [SusMoveOrCopyDirectoryContentsHelper:1731]
2020-07-30 08:10:10.7357786 5060  7604  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0x3 to generate download request for update E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200.
2020-07-30 08:10:10.9408604 5060  7604  Handler         MSP download request: MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.cab, file index = 0, type = full-file)
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0732642 5060  7600  DownloadManager DO job initialized: JobId = {0D0948D4-4807-4B12-897A-E9127D4BAF7B}
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0882516 5060  7600  DownloadManager Downloading from http://ServerHostname:8530/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2020/07/microsoftedgeenterprisex64_22af9aabb6a5fe146add075e78268cb8147dde4d.cab to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\617a0d74e2ed36d1032ce99247599a0e\MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.cab (full file).
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0889639 5060  7600  DownloadManager Update: E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200: Size calculation complete: Yes Time taken : 0 seconds
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0889670 5060  7600  DownloadManager Created download job 0D0948D4-4807-4B12-897A-E9127D4BAF7B; streaming data: No.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0896162 5060  7600  DownloadManager New download job {0D0948D4-4807-4B12-897A-E9127D4BAF7B} for UpdateId E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0912307 5060  7600  DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 0D0948D4-4807-4B12-897A-E9127D4BAF7B - Update E84D95A2-E654-470F-9A2C-88B09A3BBE9E.200
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0916004 5060  7600  DownloadManager 0 of 1 files URLs are updated.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0917123 5060  7600  DownloadManager Download job 0D0948D4-4807-4B12-897A-E9127D4BAF7B resumed.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0927692 5060  7600  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0927725 5060  7600  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 12) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0927746 5060  7600  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905}; ActivationID: 12
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0927775 5060  7600  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 13; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0927806 5060  7600  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 13.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.0931369 5060  2472  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with code Call progress and error 0
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4151175 5060  6056  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4151210 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 13) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4151227 5060  6056  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905}; ActivationID: 13
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4151255 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 14; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4151271 5060  6056  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 14.
2020-07-30 08:10:11.4155000 5060  2472  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {C34825E4-B27A-4DFC-909F-59DA10759905} with code Call progress and error 0
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3328735 5592  9732  ComApi          IUpdateServiceManager::AddService2
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3328752 5592  9732  ComApi          Service ID = {7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d}
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3328766 5592  9732  ComApi          Allow pending registration = Yes; Allow online registration = Yes; Register service with AU = Yes
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3378564 5592  9732  ComApi          Added service, URL = https://fe2cr.update.microsoft.com/v6/
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3440647 5592  9732  ComApi          * START *   Federated Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV: jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0)
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3450478 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (SR.MoUpdateOrchestrator ID 3) started; operation # 26; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3502893 5060  3172  IdleTimer       WU operation (SR.MoUpdateOrchestrator ID 3, operation # 26) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3594678 5592  3244  ComApi          Federated Search: Starting search against 1 service(s) (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0)
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3595433 5592  3244  ComApi          * START *   Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7, Flags: 0X40000010 (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0.0)
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3602816 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 4) started; operation # 29; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3696303 5060  6056  Agent           * START * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4]
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3696338 5060  6056  Agent           Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 is not in sequential scan list
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3696360 5060  6056  Agent           Added service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 to sequential scan list
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3698077 5060  2488  Agent           Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 is in sequential scan list
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3744347 5060  3812  Agent           * END * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4]
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3792932 5060  3812  Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4 (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0.0.2)
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3792970 5060  3812  Agent           Online = Yes; Interactive = No; AllowCachedResults = No; Ignore download priority = No
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3792979 5060  3812  Agent           Criteria = CallerProfile='AUv2' and IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='OptionalInstallation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1""
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3792995 5060  3812  Agent           ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3793000 5060  3812  Agent           Search Scope = {Machine}
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3793011 5060  3812  Agent           Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2020-07-30 08:11:01.3793016 5060  3812  Agent           ProcessDriverDeferrals is set
2020-07-30 08:11:02.1076733 5060  3812  Misc            Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://ServerHostname:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2020-07-30 08:11:02.2119061 5060  3812  Driver          Skipping printer driver 6 due to incomplete info or mismatched environment - HWID[(null)] Provider[Microsoft] MfgName[Microsoft] Name[Remote Desktop Easy Print] pEnvironment[Windows x64] LocalPrintServerEnv[Windows x64]
2020-07-30 08:11:02.2119223 5060  3812  Driver          Skipping printer driver 10 due to incomplete info or mismatched environment - HWID[microsoftmicrosoft_musd] Provider[Microsoft] MfgName[Microsoft] Name[Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver] pEnvironment[Windows NT x86] LocalPrintServerEnv[Windows x64]
2020-07-30 08:11:03.7076187 5340  7776  ComApi          * START *   SLS Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:03.7088966 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 5) started; operation # 32; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:03.7090349 5340  7776  ComApi          *QUEUED* SLS Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:03.7176270 5060  3304  SLS             Get response for service 2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[True]
2020-07-30 08:11:03.7176295 5060  3304  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764}/x64/10.0.19041.388/0?CH=343&L=en-US;en-GB;nl-NL&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.19041.329&MK=Dell+Inc.&MD=OptiPlex+7070
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9265969 5060  3304  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 5, operation # 32) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9348978 5060  3312  SLS             Get response for service 2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9349004 5060  3312  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764}/x64/10.0.19041.388/0?CH=343&L=en-US;en-GB;nl-NL&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.19041.329&MK=Dell+Inc.&MD=OptiPlex+7070
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9350694 5060  3312  SLS             Revision Check is on with Environment ID [StoreFrontsRS5] Revision [2]...
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9350704 5060  3312  SLS             Retrieving SLS response from server using ETAG QVZBLw7SCzNwdXLhJgNGj9GETIn2aqqVCfVbLc5UDHI=_1440"..."
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9414785 5340  4808  ComApi          *RESUMED* Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9414843 5340  4808  Api             * END *   Discovery ClientId
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9440923 5340  7776  ComApi          * START *   SLS Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9444872 5060  6056  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 6) started; operation # 37; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:03.9445306 5340  7776  ComApi          *QUEUED* SLS Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:04.1433152 5060  3312  SLS             Making request with URL HTTPS://slscr.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764}/x64/10.0.19041.388/0?CH=343&L=en-US;en-GB;nl-NL&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.19041.329&MK=Dell+Inc.&MD=OptiPlex+7070 and send SLS events.
2020-07-30 08:11:04.5360919 5060  3312  Misc            StatusCode for transaction returned from WinHttpQueryHeaders is 304
2020-07-30 08:11:04.5483585 5060  3312  SLS             Complete the request URL HTTPS://slscr.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764}/x64/10.0.19041.388/0?CH=343&L=en-US;en-GB;nl-NL&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.19041.329&MK=Dell+Inc.&MD=OptiPlex+7070 with [00000000] and http status code[304] and send SLS events.
2020-07-30 08:11:04.7959359 5060  3304  SLS             Get response for service 2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[True]
2020-07-30 08:11:04.7959384 5060  3304  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{2B81F1BF-356C-4FA1-90F1-7581A62C6764}/x64/10.0.19041.388/0?CH=343&L=en-US;en-GB;nl-NL&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.19041.329&MK=Dell+Inc.&MD=OptiPlex+7070
2020-07-30 08:11:04.7960053 5060  3304  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 6, operation # 37) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:04.8043358 5340  4808  ComApi          *RESUMED* Discovery
2020-07-30 08:11:04.8043426 5340  4808  Api             * END *   Discovery ClientId
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3720711 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://ServerHostname:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3724246 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3724311 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3724406 5060  3812  Misc            Got WSUS SimpleTargeting URL: http://ServerHostname:8530""
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3726216 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAuthorizationCookieWrapper::InitializeSimpleTargetingCookie) started; operation # 40; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3726235 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  Initializing simple targeting cookie, clientId = 456ba324-09d9-41ac-9bd7-75d9b643f739, target group = TripleOffice, DNS name = triplew10b.3audio.local
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3726241 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker    Server URL = http://ServerHostname:8530/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx
2020-07-30 08:11:06.3872697 5060  3812  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2020-07-30 08:11:08.4591796 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAuthorizationCookieWrapper::InitializeSimpleTargetingCookie, operation # 40) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:08.4593551 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetCookie_WithRecovery) started; operation # 41; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:08.4593649 5060  3812  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2020-07-30 08:11:08.4721704 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetCookie_WithRecovery, operation # 41) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:08.4721857 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8175982 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 42; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8592525 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 42) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8593017 5060  3812  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8593064 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8600954 5060  3812  DataStore       From Service: Update Id:{31A7395E-025E-4533-B289-3101A1EFB6E1.200} : Revision Id:{148140} DeploymentAction:{4}
2020-07-30 08:11:10.8960891 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 43; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:10.9042905 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 43) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:10.9042972 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 2
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1370779 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://ServerHostname:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1370790 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1370812 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1370851 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1456978 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetExtendedUpdateInfo_WithRecovery) started; operation # 44; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1489824 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetExtendedUpdateInfo_WithRecovery, operation # 44) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1490532 5060  3812  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2020-07-30 08:11:11.1490582 5060  3812  ProtocolTalker  SyncExtendedUpdateInfo - 0 bad out of 0 extended metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2020-07-30 08:11:11.2151065 5060  3812  Agent           Added update 81D1BF34-FBE1-405F-9B76-D06135277204.200 to search result
2020-07-30 08:11:11.2151167 5060  3812  Agent           Found 1 updates and 109 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 543 out of 1098 deployed entities
2020-07-30 08:11:11.3187644 5060  3812  Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, Id = 4, Exit code = 0x00000000 (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0.0.2)
2020-07-30 08:11:11.3194499 5060  3812  IdleTimer       WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 4, operation # 29) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2020-07-30 08:11:11.3303307 5592  4144  ComApi          *RESUMED*   Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0.0)
2020-07-30 08:11:11.3384729 5592  4144  ComApi          * END *   Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, Updates found = 1, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.0.0)
2020-07-30 08:11:11.3386707 5592  3244  ComApi          * END *   All federated searches have completed. Jobs = 1, Succeeded = 1, ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = jdVxEDdY/06zsN/6.0.1.1)
```

Comment: I have no experience with WSUS, however you may want to try cleaning up the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] prior to trying the update, as a dirty Component Store will often result in Windows Update related issues: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` ([man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store)). If updating from WSUS during the Audit pass, I'd just add it to the TaskSequence for that pass _(it can also be run on an offline Windows install by replacing `/Online` with `/Image:Z:\Windows` - `Z` is arbitrary)_

Comment: “since I have to access AD, I cannot set it globally via GPO” - Why exactly can’t you set it through a group policy?

Comment: Update:
The issue still persist. What i do notice is that i set the Windows Update option via powershell in the registry instead of using a GPO package. And if i open GPEDIT en go to the Windows Update section then the settings i set in the registry aren't visible there. It just shows not configured. But when i look as the ms-settings:windowsupdates then it says that the settings are managed by our company and also show which settings are managed.